# Accepting data in controller's method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How to send XML data through  Jquery ajax call and accept in Controller's method arguments of type generic object in asp.net MVC?

I have done like this but in controller's method, the value is not coming?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNF0Z.png)

Comment: You'll need to write your own ModelBinder to bind to `object` as that's not how MVC is intended to work (and you won't be able to do anything with it even if/when you do bind to it).  I think you *actually* want to bind to `string` rather than `object` as that's what XML is - just a text string (and remove the $.parse part before sending it).

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not as an image. We can't see how you construct the XML you are trying to post. i..e staticXML. But if this is a string, then change the signature on your controller to a string. thanks

Comment: It's most likely not getting through because you're not matching the jquery `data` with the MVC parameter *name*.  Just passing a random object (parsed xml).  Still think you'd be better off passing as string.

Comment: <user xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <id>34</id><firstname>3</firstname>  <lastname>3</lastname>  </user>   [this is my xml data, that i have created dynamically]

Comment: function myMethod() {
        var xmlVal = validate();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetData1",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "text/xml",
            processData: false,
            data: new DOMParser().parseFromString(xyz, "text/xml"),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Error');                
            }
        });  [this is my ajax call]

Comment: // POST: Home/GetData1
        [HttpPost]
        public string GetData1(XmlDocument objXml) {
            try
            {
                return objXml.FirstChild.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.Write(ex);
                return ex.ToString();
            }
            
        }    [this is my controller's method]

Comment: If you have extra code please use the "edit" button to add it to your question properly - thanks. Anyway, do you really have to use XML? Just use form-encoded data or JSON which are both easily accepted by MVC, are less verbose and are easier to construct in your JS code. It doesn't looks like there's anything special about your data which would mean you needed to use XML. Anyway as mentioned binding to `object` will never map any properties, because `object` doesn't have any properties. Bind to a concrete type, or `dynamic`, or (worst option) just bind to a string and parse it manually.